# Sequence of reals such that $x_{n+1}\leq ab^{n}x_{n}^{1+s}$ converges to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be decreasing sequence of non-negative reals. Suppose that there exist constants $a, s>0$ and $b>1$ such that $$x_{n+1}\leq ab^{n}x_{n}^{1+s}$$ and $$x_{0}\leq a^{-1/s}b^{-1/s^{2}}.$$  Is it true that then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}=0?$$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By induction on $n$, we check that
$$x_n\le a^{-1/s}b^{-1/s^2-n/s}$$
for all integers $n\ge0$.

Now the desired result immediately follows.

---

The condition that $x_n$ is decreasing in $n$ was not needed or used.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could the induction basis be something else here or is it related to the above condition?

Comment: @Shaq155 : The initial condition, on $x_0$, is very important here. I think the upper bound on $x_0$ cannot be improved, but I have not checked that. I am wondering where this problem came from.

Comment: Do you remember what that paper was?